# django getting month from date for aggregation

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to get a sum per month response in a DJango ORM query call:

```
models.Subscription.objects.all().extra(select={'Month': "EXTRACT(Month FROM Modified)"}).annotate(count_items=Count('Modified'))
```

my model is like this:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    SType = (
        ('C', 'Civilian'),
        ('E', 'Enlisted'),
        ('O', 'Officer'),
    )
    Subscription_Type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SType)
    Lifetime = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    Modified = models.DateField()

    objects = SubscriptionManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Member.first_name + " " + self.Member.last_name + ": " + self.Subscription_Type + "; last modified: " + self.Modified.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I am running a Postgres db background, and confirmed the column "Modified".

However, when I run the query I get this error:

```
File "/home/arcee123/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "modified" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (EXTRACT(Month FROM Modified)) AS "Month", "ifthq_sub...
```

Am I forgetting something?  I'm trying to get the count of records for each month.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at your schema? I think you just got your column name wrong.

Assuming you are using Djnago>=1.8 you can also avoid the whole issue by writing a `Func` like this one:

```
class ExtractMonth(Func):
    template = "EXTRACT(MONTH FROM %(expressions)s)"

    def __init__(self, *expressions, **extra):
        extra['output_field'] = SmallIntegerField()
        super().__init__(*expressions, **extra)
```

and using it like this:

```
Subscription.objects.annotate(Month=ExtractMonth('Modified'))\
                .values('Month').annotate(Count('Month'))
```

This way `'Modified'` is the name of the field on your model and Django resolves the column name for you.

#### Update

There is a more generic solution proposed in [this 1.9 ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25556).

Comment: ok. I tried Modified, modified, Modified_Date, and modified_Date.  It's not the column name.  it makes recommendations when I get it wrong.  THerefore, this is where I'm going to try.  Where do I put the helper class?  in models.py?  Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put it. `models.py` is fine.