# Finding events that happened on the same day in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Person model and people can have jobs:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = TextField()
    birth_date = DateField()

class Job(models.Model):
    name = TextField()
    start_date = DateField()
    person = ForeignKey('Person')
```

**I want to find people who started work on their birthday.**

Now, if I wanted to find people who started work on their *exact* birthday, I'd use:

```
from django.db.models import F
Person.objects.filter(birth_date=F('job__start_date'))
```

But this returns no one, because no one is assigned a job the they are born (hopefully).

I can find everyone who started work on April 1st:

```
Person.objects.filter(birth_date__month=4, birth_date__day=1)
```

But, if I try to combine this find people who started work during their birthday month:

```
from django.db.models import F
Person.objects.filter(birth_date__month=F('job__start_date__month'))
```

I get:

> ```
> FieldError at /data/explorer/
> Cannot resolve keyword u'month' into field. Join on 'start_date' not permitted
> ```

How can I find people who started work on their birthday?

Comment: Note, this isn't a duplicate of my other question as that was concerned with just finding events on a date in any year, not in database comparisons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708749/django-day-and-month-event-date-query

Comment: I had the same problem recently. You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897891/django-getting-month-from-date-for-aggregation/32898252#32898252).

Answer (score 1):

Lookups on Date(Time) fields in F expressions are not currently supported in django. There is still a way, hacky as it may be.

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.models import F

start_month = connection.ops.date_extract_sql('month', '%s.start_date' % Job._meta.db_table)
start_day = connection.ops.date_extract_sql('day', '%s.start_date' % Job._meta.db_table)
birth_month = connection.ops.date_extract_sql('month', 'birth_date')
birth_day = connection.ops.date_extract_sql('day', 'birth_date')

# to trigger the join and make the job table available
# otherwise the next query will fail (there's probably a less hacky way to do this)
persons = Person.objects.filter(job=F('job__pk'))

persons.extra(
    {
        'start_month': start_month,
        'start_day': start_day,
        'birth_month': birth_month,
        'birth_day': birth_day
    },
    where=['start_day=birth_day AND start_month=birth_month']
)
```